# please help me ( probabilities )

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

please let me know if my answer true or false 
 Three numbers are chosen at random without replacement from the set {0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 10}. Calculate the probabilities that for the three numbers drawn

i) None will be greater than 7,

8*7*6 / 11*10*9 = 56 / 165

ii) the smallest will be 7,

4*3*2 / 11*10*9 = 4 / 165

iii) the sum is equal to 7.

4*3*2 / 11*10*9 = 4 / 165

[image]

Comment: Smallest is $7$ if (i) they are all $\ge 7$ but (ii) they are not all $\ge 8$.

Comment: Also you may find it easier to do it in more a combinatorial way by computing how many combos have min as 7 over total combos

Comment: "please help me ( probabilities )" is not a very helpful title.  Other people with the same problem aren't likely to find it, and people capable of answering the question aren't likely to find it based on this title.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\binom{11}{3}=165$ serves as denominator.

i)  is okay.

ii) there are $3$ possibilities (leading to probability $\frac{3}{165}$):

$7-8-9$

$7-8-10$

$7-9-10$

iii) $\frac{4}{165}$ is the correct answer and can be deduced from the fact that there are $4$ possibilities (wich are all mentioned). However, I cannot find any connection with the factorization $\frac{4}{11}\times\frac{3}{10}\times\frac{2}{9}$.

Comment: There are $4$ distinct *combinations* that add up to 7, and there are $3!$ *permutations* of *each* of these four combinations.  The order in which the numbers are picked matters.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: The order in which the numbers are picked would matter if $11\times10\times9=990$ would be used as denominator. In my answer $\binom{11}{3}=165$ is used as denominator. Note that $165=990/3!$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Maybe you try to clarify the factorization that I mention as not understood? If so then what is the reason to write $4\times3!/11\times10\times9$ as $\frac{4}{11}\times\frac{3}{10}\times\frac{2}{9}$?

Comment: $\require{cancel}\dfrac{\text{favoured combinations} \times \text{permutations of each}}{\text{total combinations} \times \text{permutations of such}}=\frac{4\times 3!}{\binom{11}{3}\times 3!} = \dfrac{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{\frac{11\times 10\times 9 \times \cancel{8!}}{\cancel{8!}\cancel{3!}}\times \cancel{3!}} = \dfrac{4\times 3\times 2}{11\times 10\times 9}$

Comment: Or if you prefer, simply: $\frac{4}{\binom{11}{3}}=\frac{4}{\frac{11\times 10\times 9}{3\times 2\times 1}} = \frac{4\times 3\times 2}{11\times 10\times 9}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, off course. But that is just arithmetic. Let's say then that the only connection that I can find with the factorization is the fact that it ends up with the same (and correct) outcome.

Answer (score 0):

iii)

The laplace definition of probability is the ratio of the number of favored events to the number of total possible events

number of total possible events:$11\cdot 10\cdot 9$

For the number of favored Events I would write down all the combinations with the sum of 7:

016 (6)

025 (6)

034 (6)

124 (6)

To get all the permutations you have to sum all the number in the brackets.

For example 016 can be written as: 016. 061, 160, 106, 601, 610

greetings,

calculus